# Wordpress mysql query with many joins

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, join

Hey Guys i am trying to create something like facebook like 
stuff

Friends_list Table

```
 | id | user_id | Friend_id | status
 |  1 |   1     |    24     |   P
 |  2 |   18    |    26     |   P
```

User Table

```
 | ID | email   | password  |  ..N
 |  1 |   xx    |    xx     |   xx
 |  2 |   xx    |    xx     |   xx
```

from those both table i want to get all the users listed without the users whose status was P or B in friends list table it seems to be simple using joins but in wordpress this code is not working and the query is as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.ID, u1.user_email, fl.status, ud.value, uad.image_name
FROM wp_users u1
LEFT JOIN Friends_list fl ON fl.Friend_id=u1.ID
LEFT JOIN user_details ud ON ud.user_id=u1.ID
LEFT JOIN user_additional_details uad ON uad.user_id=u1.ID
WHERE u1.ID != '".$user->ID."' AND fl.status NOT IN ('P', 'B')
```

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your PHP code trying to do so?

Comment: i need the sql query to be corrected and i have posted above no php codes along with it

Comment: Does you query work when you run it on your database directly?

Comment: No i didn get any result

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

have you considered replacing:

```
WHERE u1.ID != '".$user->ID."' AND fl.status NOT IN ('P', 'B')
```

with

```
WHERE u1.ID = '".$user->ID."' AND fl.status NOT IN ('P', 'B')
```

?
can you explain what $user->id is ?

Comment: $user->ID is the one who is logged on

Comment: by the way above solution is not working though, anyhow thanks

Comment: can you post the definition of Friends_list ?

Comment: please find the fiddle out there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281610/sql-query-with-two-joins-and-a-simple-logic/47281870?noredirect=1#comment81515157_47281870