# sql query with two joins and a simple logic

Tags: php, mysql

Please find the fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a4aff/7

**Friends_list** Table

```
 | id | user_id | Friend_id | status
 |  1 |   1     |    24     |   P
 |  2 |   18    |    26     |   P
```

**User** Table

```
| ID | email   | password  |  ..N
 |  1 |   xx    |    xx     |   xx
 |  2 |   xx    |    xx     |   xx
```

from those both table i want to get all the users listed without the users whose status was P or B in friends list table it seems to be simple using joins but in wordpress this code is not working and the query is as below.

```
select DISTINCT u.ID, u.user_nicename from wp_users u
LEFT JOIN friends_list f ON f.friend_id=u.ID
WHERE f.status  NOT IN ('P', 'B')
```

Comment: In the fiddle you are missing `NOT` from `f.status  NOT IN ('P', 'B')`

Comment: no if i use IN  iam getting correct result, where the status = P, but if i use not in i have to display all result without p but iam not getting it

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj try my answer below. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query as below. If you only want data from first table then no need join query only use inner query

```
select DISTINCT u.ID, u.user_nicename from wp_users u WHERE u.ID not in 
(select f.friend_id from friends_list f where f.status IN ('P', 'B')) order by u.ID;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a4aff/70)

**EDIT**

```
select DISTINCT u.ID, u.user_nicename from wp_users u
LEFT JOIN friends_list f ON f.friend_id=u.ID
WHERE f.status NOT IN ('P', 'B') OR f.status IS NULL ORDER BY u.ID
```

Comment: thanks cool code works but the issue is if user 1 and user 2 gives request to  two different people both of the people were not found in both of user 1 and user 2's profile

Comment: Will you explain with example data?

Comment: if user admin sends request to mike and pope, and rock send request to justin and ray four of justin, ray, mike, pope where missing in admin and rock

Comment: Try edited answer. Hope it will work now @PattatharasuNataraj

Answer (score 3):

You must join tables with user id like below:

LEFT JOIN friends_list f ON **f.user_id**=u.ID

```
select DISTINCT u.ID, u.user_nicename from wp_users u
    LEFT JOIN friends_list f ON f.user_id=u.ID
    WHERE f.status  NOT IN ('P', 'B')
```

Add two records at **friends_list** table with  **Q** and **Z** status for testing

```
INSERT INTO `friends_list` (`id`, `user_id`, `Friend_id`, `status`) VALUES
(80, 1, 26, 'P'),
(79, 18, 26, 'P'),
(78, 1, 24, 'P'),
(79, 20, 24, 'Q'),
(80, 21, 24, 'Z');
```

[sqlfiddle working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5225f/1)

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want ALL user except the those who has P or B as status. To get those users that don't have a value in the friends_list table at all you can add a null check to your query.

```
select DISTINCT u.ID, u.user_nicename from wp_users u
LEFT JOIN friends_list f ON f.friend_id=u.ID
WHERE f.status NOT IN ('P', 'B') OR f.status IS NULL
```

I'm also unsure if you're joining on the right column? Should it be user_id instead of friend_id?

Comment: This should work 
`SELECT u.ID, u.user_nicename from wp_users u LEFT JOIN friends_list f ON f.user_id = u.ID WHERE f.status NOT IN ('P', 'B') OR f.status IS NULL GROUP BY u.ID`

Comment: @Soliyappan as far as I know GROUP BY is meant to be used with aggregates. In this case he wants unique results, which is what DISTINCT is for. So I would not change from distinct to group by in this case, although group by will give the same result, it's not what's it meant for.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the binding column like this :-

```
select DISTINCT u.ID, u.user_nicename from wp_users u
LEFT JOIN friends_list f ON f.user_id=u.ID
WHERE f.status NOT IN ('P', 'B');
```

Comment: thankss  for your answer this too not working have you checked fiddle?

Comment: Yes, its working in fiddle. Just change the status from `P or B` to any other letter like `A` and check the result...

Comment: nope, you misunderstood i guess, if i use IN  iam getting correct result, where the status = P, but if i use NOT IN i have to display all result without p but iam not getting it

Comment: For better performance filter as early as possible: `select DISTINCT u.ID, u.user_nicename FROM wp_users u
LEFT JOIN friends_list f ON f.user_id=u.ID AND f.status NOT IN ('P', 'B')`

This will not be noticable until more joins are added, but the WHERE statement is executed after the joins are done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query, your fiddle is showing blank result as you have only data with P Status, try to add one more entry with some other status then you will get the result.

```
select DISTINCT u.ID, u.user_nicename from wp_users u left join friends_list f 
on f.friend_id=u.ID where f.status is NULL
```